# Prevent Resubmissions for PHP Contact form

Tags: php

This is the code for the form.

```
 <?php 
    if ($_POST) {
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $company = $_POST['company'];
            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            $checkbox = '';
            if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
            $checkbox = 'Yes';} else{
                $checkbox = 'No' ;}
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
            $to = 'imvael@gmail.com, vnikolic1@cps.edu'; 
            $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';
            $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Company: $company\n Phone: $phone\n Opt In?: $checkbox\n Message:\n $message";
            $headers = 'From: webmaster@bradfordsystems.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' .$email . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

            // Check if name has been entered
            if (!$_POST['name']) {
                $errName = 'Please enter your name';
            }

            // Check if email has been entered and is valid
            if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
            }


            // Check if name has been entered
            if (!$_POST['phone']) {
                $errName = 'Please enter your phone number';
            }


            //Check if message has been entered
            if (!$_POST['message']) {
                $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
            }

    // then after the posting of the form data

    // validation


    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == '')  {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
            header("Location: thankyou.php"); /* Redirect browser */
            exit();
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
        }
    } 

    }

     header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
       exit();
    }
```

This is the form itself

```
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row">


<div class="col _66">
     <?php echo $result; ?> 
<form role="form" name="contactForm" id="contactForm"  method="post" action="contact.php#contactForm">
 <p>
       We welcome your feedback and inquiries. Please use the form below to get in touch.
       </p>

   <div class="row">

       <div class="col">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>" required>
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
       </div>


        <div class="col">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Company Email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>" required>
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['company']); ?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
           <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']); ?> placeholder="Phone" required> 
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errPhone</p>";?>
        </div>
     </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
             <input type="number" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['zipcode']); ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="col">
             <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox"> <span id="optInText">YES, I want a Free Workspace Evaluation!</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
         <p class="antispam">Leave this empty: <input type="text" name="url" /></p>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">


        <div class="col submit-col">
                <p>Questions or Comments?</p>

        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your questions or comments here" style="height:200px"> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']); ?></textarea>
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
         <button class="btn btn-dark hvr-underline-from-left" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">Submit Request</button>    



    </div>
        </div>


  </form>
</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am writing a contact form script from scratch The code is working correctly, but I am unable to prevent resubmissions if they user refreshed the page or press the submit buton more then once.

Also is it a bad practice to use self submitting contact forms?

Comment: Are you familiar with PRG? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get It's actually possible to implement it in a single script if you need to.

Comment: reading up on it. thanks!

Comment: If you want you can use a temporary "session" or "cookie" and check: if that user has a session set, disable the send button. Or you can create a temporary file(XML for example) to store the IP address for 24h for example, controlling with a cronjob.